# Type mismatch when using "while(line = reader.readLine() != null)"

Tags: java, type-mismatch

So I am trying to simply print each line of my buffered read to see if It is outputting correctly but I am getting an error in eclipse and at runtime. Absolutely everywhere I look the code for outputting buffered reader is

```
    String line;
    while(line = myReader.readLine() != null){
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

This throws an error saying that "Type mismatch cannot convert from boolean to string." If I change line to a boolean variable it runs and prints "true" three times which is how many lines I am expecting, so does anyone have any idea how I can print the actual text? I am assuming it is throwing the error because != null will return true or false but I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 7):

This is because [higher Operator Precedence of equality v/s assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

From the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):

> When operators of equal precedence appear in the same expression, a rule must govern which is evaluated first. **All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.**

(emphasis mine)
[image]
So

```
line = myReader.readLine() != null
```

Gets evaluated as per precedence as

```
line = (myReader.readLine() != null)
```

which is an attempt to assign boolean to `line`, giving the error.

### Correct usage:

```
(line = myReader.readLine()) != null
```

Comment: It's because of the operator precedence of `=` as against `!=`, and that's why additional parentheses fixes it. If it was because of right-to-left, that wouldn't fix it.

Answer (score 5):

`while ( (line = myReader.readLine()) != null ) {` will do. you forgot to put `()` correctly.

The problem was, `myReader.readLine() != null` part was evaluated first.